# How to update one row (only one) if the row is duplicated? DB2

Tags: database, db2

I am able to add a rownumber when i make a select, but i can't figure out how to use the row number on the update command

```
    SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY numb) AS CODE, numb FROM myDB2.tblRep
    WHERE comp = 'FV'
        AND TRIM(UPPER(numb)) LIKE UPPER(TRIM('01key%'))
```

I have also tried something like what is here (http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/446226-update-duplicate-rows), which on my code is something like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM myDB2.tblRep AS o
    WHERE o.comp = 'FV'
      AND TRIM(UPPER(o.numb)) LIKE UPPER(TRIM('01key%'))
      AND ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM myDB2.tblRep  AS i
    WHERE o.numb = i.numb ) > 1
```

I always make the select before i make an update, but it returns the rows with their duplicated, so i don't believe this will work

Ideas? Please

Answer (score 0):

That might be simply

```
UPDATE (
  SELECT * FROM myDB2.tblRep
  WHERE comp = 'FV' AND TRIM(UPPER(numb)) LIKE UPPER(TRIM('01key%'))
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
)
SET yourcolumn = 'yourvalue'
```

This should work on all recent DB2 versions.

Comment: But i think i might have to do this with every duplicated row, i mean, i have these values: 01key10, 01key12, 01key13... etc, and all those values have duplicate rows, and using that query, i will have to specify the complete numb value of every duplicated row

Comment: Then you have to rephrase your question and provide some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT ..., ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ...
                                  ORDER BY ...) AS RN 
    FROM myDB2.tblRep
    WHERE comp = 'FV'
      AND TRIM(UPPER(numb)) LIKE UPPER(TRIM('01key%'))
) SET the_col = ...
WHERE RN = 1;
```